# Can someone suggest me good opencourseware links for learning computational biology basics?

Tags: bioinformatics

My internet is slow and I have only 1GB data usage allowed for this month. And I want to make maximum out of it for learning some basics of computational biology.

Which are the best online course (freely available lectures) suggestions for me?

Comment: coursera has some good courses!

Comment: MIT-OCW also has decent video lectures.. Bulk download the videos and watch them on your player..

Comment: ok let me see. But internet is expensive for me still. :(

Answer (score 2):

http://ocw.mit.edu/courses/health-sciences-and-technology/hst-508-genomics-and-computational-biology-fall-2002/audio-lectures/

Download all the slides if you want good resources.

Comment: OK let me see those.